# Running AddressSanitizer with DPDK

Tags: dpdk, address-sanitizer

I am trying to debug a potential memory corruption in my application that is using DPDK 21.11 using https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/prog_guide/asan.html

I have installed libasan as required. However, I am unable to compile DPDK 21.11 when I add -Db_sanitize=address to the meson option.

```
20:44:42 [root]:  yum install libasan
Package libasan-8.5.0-10.el8.x86_64 is already installed.


meson -Db_sanitize=address -Dprefix=/ build

The Meson build system
Version: 0.61.2
Source dir: /root/repo/gNB_CU/ngp/thirdparty/dpdk/dpdk-21.11
Build dir: /root/repo/gNB_CU/ngp/thirdparty/dpdk/dpdk-21.11/build
Build type: native build
Program cat found: YES (/usr/bin/cat)
WARNING: You should add the boolean check kwarg to the run_command call.
         It currently defaults to false,
         but it will default to true in future releases of meson.
         See also: https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/issues/9300
Project name: DPDK
Project version: 21.11.0
C compiler for the host machine: cc (gcc 10.3.1 "cc (GCC) 10.3.1 20210422 (Red Hat 10.3.1-1)")
C linker for the host machine: cc ld.bfd 2.35-8
Host machine cpu family: x86_64
Host machine cpu: x86_64
Program pkg-config found: YES (/usr/bin/pkg-config)
Program check-symbols.sh found: YES (/root/repo/gNB_CU/ngp/thirdparty/dpdk/dpdk-21.11/buildtools/check-symbols.sh)
Program options-ibverbs-static.sh found: YES (/root/repo/gNB_CU/ngp/thirdparty/dpdk/dpdk-21.11/buildtools/options-ibverbs-static.sh)
Program objdump found: YES (/opt/rh/gcc-toolset-10/root/usr/bin/objdump)
Program python3 found: YES (/usr/bin/python3.6)
WARNING: Python files installed by Meson might not be found by python interpreter.
 This warning can be avoided by setting "python.platlibdir" option.
WARNING: Python files installed by Meson might not be found by python interpreter.
 This warning can be avoided by setting "python.purelibdir" option.
Program cat found: YES (/usr/bin/cat)
Checking for size of "void *" : 8
Checking for size of "void *" : 8
Library m found: YES
Library numa found: YES
Has header "numaif.h" : YES
Library libfdt found: NO
Library libexecinfo found: NO
Found pkg-config: /usr/bin/pkg-config (1.4.2)
Run-time dependency libarchive found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Run-time dependency libbsd found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Run-time dependency jansson found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Run-time dependency libpcap found: YES 1.9.1
Has header "pcap.h" with dependency libpcap: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wextra: YES
config/meson.build:290: WARNING: Consider using the built-in warning_level option instead of using "-Wextra".
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wcast-qual: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wdeprecated: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wformat: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wformat-nonliteral: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wformat-security: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wmissing-declarations: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wmissing-prototypes: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wnested-externs: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wold-style-definition: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wpointer-arith: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wsign-compare: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wstrict-prototypes: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wundef: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wwrite-strings: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-address-of-packed-member: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-packed-not-aligned: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-missing-field-initializers: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-zero-length-bounds: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -mno-avx512f: YES
config/x86/meson.build:10: WARNING: Binutils error with AVX512 assembly, disabling AVX512 support
Compiler for C supports arguments -mavx512f: YES
Checking if "AVX512 checking" compiles: YES
Fetching value of define "__SSE4_2__" : 1
Fetching value of define "__AES__" : 1
Fetching value of define "__AVX__" : 1
Fetching value of define "__AVX2__" :
Fetching value of define "__AVX512BW__" :
Fetching value of define "__AVX512CD__" :
Fetching value of define "__AVX512DQ__" :
Fetching value of define "__AVX512F__" :
Fetching value of define "__AVX512VL__" :
Fetching value of define "__PCLMUL__" : 1
Fetching value of define "__RDRND__" :
Fetching value of define "__RDSEED__" :
Fetching value of define "__VPCLMULQDQ__" :

config/meson.build:427:8: ERROR: C shared or static library 'asan' not found
```

How do I link the asan library ?

Comment: Did you install ASAN library? Or better question if your gcc is newer why not use gcc asan feature itself?

Comment: I have installed libasan-8.5.0-10.el8.x86_64 , but there might be some linking issue?